# SauceConnect on Codeship

Tags: saucelabs, codeship

I have a SauceConnect tunnel up & running on my codeship build.  It connects--the tunnel is alive!  This is evidenced by `sc` stdout, as well as from saucelabs.com.

If I launch a server to serve a static website on my CI box, from another shell I can curl it.  I get back the `<html>` doc as expected.

Cool!  So,

- the local static server is up and serving content (verified), *and*
- the sauceconnect tunnel is up.

However, when looking at the screencast from saucelabs:

[image]

Bummer!  The exact same branch running the same bits works from my personal host.  Even running a manual test from saucelabs over the tunnel does not work.

The log of the failing pipeline is here: https://gist.github.com/cdaringe/b5e92aab21c2a6af9672fbffb77ad8bc

I'm not certain that it's fully relevant, but to produce a working test (exit 0) using loosely the same bits:

- check out https://github.com/Tripwire/octagon/pull/68
- `yarn`, `yarn build`, `yarn run styleguide:build`
- set SAUCE_USERNAME, SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY, per the usual
- `yarn test`

Comment: hmmm. with no code change or configuration change, i was just able to establish the connection from sauce to my CI server in a manual test. more investigating is required.

Comment: arg, just cant put my finger on it.  works great from my own box _and_ when doing manual testing on CI.  the above still occurs.